# page fault in copy_to_user, how kernel map a page for user space address?

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtual-memory

I've learned that when a page fault occurs in `copy_to_user` function, the exception table will be used.

But I found almost all fix would just set the return value and jump to the next instruction after the one which triggers page fault.

Where does the kernel do the mapping work for user space address? 

I mean at least there is some place kernel will modify page table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very **unclear**, a `copy_to_user` is basically a function for copying data from **kernel-space** to **user-space**. Mainly for security reasons as we don't want to give user access to kernel data structures and kernel-space. So we need a mechanism to request from the kernel to give us this data.

A new mapping will be added in the page-tables indeed. The mapping is done in 
   `kernel-space` where the `page-tables` reside.